# How to automate the creation of elasticsearch index patterns for all days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, kibana-7

I am using cloudwatch subscription filter which automatically sends logs to elasticsearch aws and then I use Kibana from there. The issue is that everyday cloudwatch creates a new indice due to which I have to manually create the new index pattern each day in kibana. Accordingly I will have to create new monitors and alerts in kibana as well each day. I have to automate this somehow. Also if there is better option with which I can go forward would be great. I know datadog is one good option.

Comment: What is the naming pattern of your indices?

Comment: cwl--aws-containerinsights-eks-cluster-for-test-host-2021.01.19...something like this the last number represents the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical work flow will look like this (there are other methods)

- Choose a pattern when creating an index. Like staff-202001, staff-202002, etc
- Add each index to an alias. Like staff

This can be achieved in multiple ways, easiest is to create a template with index pattern , alias and mapping.
Example: Any new index created matching the pattern `staff-*` will be assigned with given mapping and attached to alias `staff`  and we can query `staff` instead of individual indexes and setup alerts.

We can use cwl--aws-containerinsights-eks-cluster-for-test-host to run queries.

```
POST _template/cwl--aws-containerinsights-eks-cluster-for-test-host
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "cwl--aws-containerinsights-eks-cluster-for-test-host-*"
  ],
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "firstName": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {
    "cwl--aws-containerinsights-eks-cluster-for-test-host": {}
  }
}
```

Note: If unsure of mapping, we can remove mapping section.

Comment: This sounds good enough. But unfortunately I cannot see the option for templates in management section of Kibana as I am using the dashboard provided by Aws. Can we somehow enhance it to use templates functionality?

Comment: There will be `Dev Tools` option from Kibana UI for running queries or you can access url like this `https://my***-****.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?_g=()`

Comment: In dev tools I am able to run the query and I am getting acknowleged true as the response. What should I do after that? How to implement it to create index pattern?

Comment: Thats all. nothing else is needed. Next time an index is created matching that pattern, it will be automatically assigned to given alias `cwl--aws-containerinsights-eks-cluster-for-test-host`, you can simply use alias to run queries.

Comment: Oh Okay. So I just created the index pattern matching the given alias. Now any new indice which would come up in elasticsearch it would form a new index which would automatically attach to the index pattern already created right?

Comment: great, glad I could help. For your last comment, every index created matching the pattern will be attached to the `alias`. so, we use `alias` to query, Alias is like a common name for all indexes.